# Format XML Document created with PHP - DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am trying to format visually how my XML file looks when it is output.  Right now if you go [here](http://www.levijackson.net/test/crawl-curl/sitemap.xml) and view the source you will see what the file looks like.

The PHP I have that creates the file is: (Note, $links_array is an array of urls)

```
        header('Content-Type: text/xml');
        $sitemap = new DOMDocument;
        
        // create root element
        $root = $sitemap->createElement("urlset");
        $sitemap->appendChild($root);
         
        $root_attr = $sitemap->createAttribute('xmlns'); 
        $root->appendChild($root_attr); 

        $root_attr_text = $sitemap->createTextNode('http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'); 
        $root_attr->appendChild($root_attr_text); 

        
        
        foreach($links_array as $http_url){
        
                // create child element
                $url = $sitemap->createElement("url");
                $root->appendChild($url);
                
                $loc = $sitemap->createElement("loc");
                $lastmod = $sitemap->createElement("lastmod");
                $changefreq = $sitemap->createElement("changefreq");
                
                $url->appendChild($loc);
                $url_text = $sitemap->createTextNode($http_url);
                $loc->appendChild($url_text);
                
                $url->appendChild($lastmod);
                $lastmod_text = $sitemap->createTextNode(date("Y-m-d"));
                $lastmod->appendChild($lastmod_text);
                
                $url->appendChild($changefreq);
                $changefreq_text = $sitemap->createTextNode("weekly");
                $changefreq->appendChild($changefreq_text);
                
        }
        
        $file = "sitemap.xml";
        $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("Can't open the sitemap file.");
        fwrite($fh, $sitemap->saveXML());
        fclose($fh);
    }
```

As you can tell by looking at the source, the file isn't as readable as I would like  it to be.  Is there any way for me to format the nodes?

Thanks,
Levi

Comment: You can add a xml header and open it in FireFox. This will show a nice formatted version off your xml document

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checkout the [formatOutput](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.formatoutput) setting in `DOMDocument`.

```
$sitemap->formatOutput = true
```

Answer (score 0):

not just PHP, there is a stylesheet for XML: [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/), which can format XML into sth looks good.

Comment: Ah ok, I have done some basic XSLT stylesheets before.  I was hoping there was a way to at least put line breaks in after a node was created with PHP.

Comment: answer from above formatOutput do the job? your question seems mis leading this way....